# /bin/sh: capture stderr into a variable

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, stderr

In my script, I have a complicated command that generates output both on `stdout` and `stderr`. I need to capture both into separate variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
A=$(command)
```

How can I "capture" `stderr` into a variable `B` ?

I have tried some variations with `2>&1` and `read` but that does not work:

```
A=$(some_command) 2>&1 | read B
echo $B
```

or

```
{ OUT="$(command)" 2>&1 | read B ; }
echo $B
```

The only way that works is to redirect `stderr` into a temporary file, and then read it back. But that seems like a dirty hack. Is there a way to do it without using temporary files?

## UPDATE

to clarify, both `stdout` and `stderr` will be multi-line outputs.

Comment: Does your `read B` command imply that you only expect to read a single line from the standard error stream?

Comment: @Kusalananda - no. I expect multi-line errors. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: See also [Read / write to the same file descriptor with shell redirection](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/472585)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, using a file might be the simplest way to go. But let's make some assumptions here, and say you want `stdout` as a one-line variable, and don't care about `stderr` being 1 line (or else flatten it too). Then let's use a simple script for testing - where "2" goes to `stderr` and the other lines to stdout:

```
> cat outerr.sh
echo 1
echo 2 >&2
echo 3
> ./outerr.sh
1
2
3
> ./outerr.sh 2>/dev/null
1
3
```

Then you can do something like:

```
(echo $(./outerr.sh) # Collect and flatten the stdout output 
                     # Meanwhile stderr flows through the pipe
) 2>&1|{
        read err     # This assumes stderr is one line only
        read out
        echo "err=$err"
        echo "out=$out"
}
```

or if stderr could be multiline, then

```
(echo $(./outerr.sh) # Collect and flatten the stdout output 
                     # Meanwhile stderr flows through the pipe
) 2>&1|tac|{         # reverse the output so the stdout line comes first
        read out
        err=$(tac)   # reverse lines again, back to the original line order
        echo "err=$err"
        echo "out=$out"
}
```

with output

```
err=2
out=1 3
```

If `stdout` lines need to be preserved, you could e.g. embed \n line breaks, or again, just go back to using a file instead.